# git pushed changes are not reflecting on heroku server

Tags: node.js, git, api, heroku, server

I have a sever on heroku. I'm making changes on my project (for ex. adding something inside my JSON file). I'm pushing my changes on heroku/master branch like this:

```
git add .
git commit -am "changes in json file"
git push heroku master
```

I'm getting "Everything up-to-date". When I'm reloading the server the changes that I made don't appear, it makes sense because if I'm trying to push to my heroku master brench I'm gerring "Everything up-to-date" but I'm expecting to show me the changes and to restart the server automatically.

Can you help me?
[image]

For any additional informations please ask me!

Comment: What do you see when you run `git status` after making some changes? and are you sure that you are not including the files that you are editing in `.gitignore`?

Comment: There is nothing to commit, as it literally says "nothing to commit, working tree clean" maybe you are changing a file that is in `.gitignore`

Comment: here is the link to my repository https://github.com/octavi42/sighisoaraPinApi . How do I see if my file is .gitignore?

Comment: when I run "git status" I get: On branch master
               Your branch is up to date with 'heroku/master'.

               nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Are you sure you're actually modifying the file? Please modify the file, try `git status` and then paste the output you're getting here.

Comment: @Maroun Yes I modified words.json

Comment: @OctaCZO What does `git status` return?

Comment: git status returns: On branch master / Your branch is up to date with 'heroku/master'. 
 / nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @OctaCZO are you on `master` branch?

Comment: I’m on master but if I run “git switch heroku/master” I get: “fatal: a branch is expected, gotremote branch ‘heroku/maste’” and if I’m truing to switch the branch inside GitHub Desktop app I’m getting “A branch with that name already exists.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!
I don't know what I did to solve the problem, it solved after I made a new project following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P86N9FqNqso&list=LL69VX7JLGdfJjh-p8M1RzVw&index=2&t=0s
It might be possible due to the fact that I wasn't in the right folder, I didn't check the folder I was in, I'm not saying that that was my problem but I consider it a possibility.
It works now, thanks for helping and if you have the same problem I can suggest to you rechecking if you are in the right folder, your project folder, or check the tutorial I linked above.